# php post not reading variables

Tags: php, express, axios

.vue :

```
const connect = () => {
  console.log(url_img.value); // Utilisez this.url_img pour accéder à la valeur liée par v-model
  axios
    .post("http://localhost:3001/api-php/test.php", {
      var: url_img.value, // Utilisez this.url_img pour accéder à la valeur liée par v-model
    })
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
    });
};
```

.cjs :

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const { exec } = require("child_process");
const cors = require("cors");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // Middleware pour analyser le corps des requêtes POST

// Définissez le chemin vers votre répertoire contenant les scripts PHP
const phpScriptsPath = path.join(__dirname, "/api-php");

// Middleware pour gérer les fichiers PHP
app.all(/.+\.php$/, (req, res) => {
  const phpScript = path.join(
    phpScriptsPath,
    req.path.replace(/^\/api-php\//, "")
  );
  const phpCgiCommand = `php-cgi -f ${phpScript}`;

  exec(phpCgiCommand, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (error) {
      console.error("Erreur lors de l'exécution du script PHP :", error);
      res.status(500).send("Erreur lors de l'exécution du script PHP");
      return;
    }

    if (stderr) {
      console.error("Erreur PHP :", stderr);
      res.status(500).send("Erreur PHP");
      return;
    }

    res.send(stdout);
  });
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 3001;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Serveur en cours d'exécution sur le port ${port}`);
});
```

.php :

```
<?php
$var = $_POST['var'];
echo $var;
?>
```

error :

$_POST['var']; send **Undefined array key "var" in code

the variable  url_img. is not null cause a can see it in the request header : data: "{"var":"ff"}"

I tried to add the app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); , but this didn't worked

Comment: What do you get if you do `var_dump($_POST);`?

Comment: You're executing PHP on the command line, not from an HTTP request.  Shouldn't you be sending data as command-line arguments?

Comment: And...why on earth are you forwarding data from express to PHP anyway? What can PHP do that you can't already do with server-side JavaScript? Bit of a strange use case, if you ask me.

Comment: Aynber : I'll try to do that and I let you know the result 

David : Thanks for the idea, I honestly didn't thought about that

ADyson : That a school project which imposes the usage of PHOP, I totally agree that I could do without

Comment: `That a school project which imposes the usage of PHOP`...then why not just use PHP _directly_, without the involvement of expressJS? That would make a _lot_ more sense. Having 2 server-side languages like this is daft - you're making it far more complicated than it needs to be. It's not an architecture that anyone would use in real life, either.